# C# Accessing protected fields

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to organise a scene graph.
I have general class SceneNode:

```
public class SceneNode
{
    protected SceneNode prev, next;
    protected SceneNodeContainer parent;

    public SceneNode Parent { get { return parent; } }
    public SceneNode PreviousNode { get { return prev; } }
    public SceneNode NextNode { get { return next; } }
}
```

I also have class SceneNodeContainer, which is like this:

```
public class SceneNodeContainer : SceneNode
{
    SceneNode firstChild, lastChild;

    public SceneNode FirstChild { get { return firstChild; } }
    public SceneNode LastChild { get { return lastChild; } }

    public void Add(SceneNode node)
    {
        Debug.Assert(node != null);
        Debug.Assert(node.parent == null);

        node.parent = this;
        node.prev = lastChild;
        node.next = null;

        if (lastChild == null)
        {
            lastChild = node;
            firstChild = lastChild;
        }
        else
        {
            lastChild.next = node;
            lastChild = node;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(SceneNode node)
    {
        Debug.Assert(node != null);
        Debug.Assert(node.parent == this);

        //unlink node
        if (node.next != null)
            node.next.prev = node.prev;

        if (node.prev != null)
            node.prev.next = node.next;

        if (node == firstChild)
            firstChild = node.next;

        if (node == lastChild)
            lastChild = node.prev;

        node.parent = null;
        node.next = null;
        node.prev = null;
    }
}
```

IntelliSense says that node.parent and other protected fields cannot be accessed from SceneNodeContainer. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 7):

You can't, because of the way protected works - it only allows access to protected fields of objects which are known to be of the child type (or a subtype). So if `node` were a `SceneNodeContainer` variable, you'd have access to the fields - but otherwise, you don't.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# 4 spec:

> When a protected instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a protected internal instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the access must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared. Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it. This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing protected members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

(As an aside, I'd personally avoid protected fields anyway. I make non-constant fields private in almost all cases.)

Comment: "I make non-constant fields private in almost all cases." - do you consider that a symptom of poor design or just personal preference?

Comment: @William: Design. Fields are an implementation detail and should not be part of the exposed API

Comment: Well, as it usually happens with me, the solution appeared just after posting this question. SceneNode class will now have AddAfter and AddBefore methods and SceneNodeContainer will have an empty SceneNode as first child (so it's like headed list). And I agree about hiding fields. I open them only in basic structs.

Comment: @JonSkeet if we use `protected internal` we can access fields. but is there any drawback?

Comment: @UnhandledException: Yes - it's violating encapsulation in the same way. The field should be private to keep the implementation details hidden from other classes, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

use `protected internal` instead of `protected` then you can access from sub classes of same assembly.

```
public class SceneNode
{
    protected internal SceneNode prev, next;
    protected internal SceneNodeContainer parent;

    public SceneNode Parent { get { return parent; } }
    public SceneNode PreviousNode { get { return prev; } }
    public SceneNode NextNode { get { return next; } }
}
```

Comment: `protected internal` gives access to *all* classes within the same assembly *and* all subclasses - but subclasses from other assemblies will only get the same access as if it were protected... so effectively your suggestion is somewhat equivalent to making it internal. (In that that's why it works here.) Personally I'd try to stick to private fields instead.